# Vaadin 14 - Service worker and manifest is not created

Tags: java, vaadin, progressive-web-apps, vaadin-flow, vaadin14

I am currently working on a PWA in Vaadin14. My current goal is to show up the installation window in the browser but I simply can't get it.

I tried to use https://vaadin.com/pwa/learn/installing-applications as guide. I am having a valid certificate and use a HTTPS connection for the application in the browser. The following `@PWA` annotation is used:

```
@Route("main") 
@PWA(name = "Test", shortName = "Test", backgroundColor = "#227aef", themeColor = "#227aef") 
public class MainView extends AppLayout implements RouterLayout, BeforeEnterObserver {
```

I tried it with Chrome and Firefox, both didn't show an installation window.

It is mentioned that Vaadin creates a Web App Manifest and ServiceWorker by its own (https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/pwa/tutorial-pwa-pwa-with-flow.html)

> Vaadin server automatically serves the web manifest, service worker,
>   icons, offline page, and installation prompt, and adds the necessary
>   additions to the application headers.

I cant find the files anywhere after my project is build though. Where are they stored?

What am I missing here?

Edit: Firefox has the following config which I set to `true`.

> Service workers can be unavailable if the dom.serviceWorkers.enable
>   preference is set to false in about:config.

Edit2: I could verify that Firefox does not start a Service-Worker for my application.

Comment: Have you checked that the manifest that Vaadin creates has the next fields?: ```short_name or name, icons (192px & 512px), start_url and display (fullscreen or standalone or minimal-ui)```

Comment: I have searched everywhere for a manifest but it seems like it isnt even created.

Comment: You can check it on the browser. On Chrome for example: press F12 >> Application >> Manifest

Comment: There is no manifest or service worker of my aplication shown for me. Same in Firefox. I tried the Vaadin Bakery App and evertyhing worked fine. My application does not, somehow.

Comment: Does your PWA pass the Chrome Lighthouse tests using that same HTTPS url? Running that usually tells you if anything is wrong and hints on how to fix.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I will give it a try on monday when I am back at work!

Comment: The Lighthouse tests confirms what i thought. No service worker is running and no manifest is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to solve this issue. Definetly took some time. The issue was that my custom VaadinServlet did not recognize my @PWA annotation so I had to add it manually.

```
public class VaadinFlowServlet extends com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet {

@Override
public void init(ServletConfig servletConfig) throws ServletException {
    var registry = 
    ApplicationRouteRegistry.getInstance(servletConfig.getServletContext());
    registry.setPwaConfigurationClass(LoginView.class); // <-- contains @PWA

    super.init(servletConfig);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to show the A2HS (Add To Home Screen) dialog on a mobile device you should have a running service worker and a web manifest file correctly configured.

In case of a desktop browser, you would not see a window popup (unless vaadin itself opens one for you, but I do not this technology) but a (+) icon in the browser address bar (here for Chrome):

[image]

You should first find out if the service worker and web manifest are correctly generated. Maybe they are in a /bin folder, a bit hidden within the project structure.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I could verify that no manifest or serviceworker are created. Any idea why?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know vaadin14, therefore I cannot tell why the two files are not created. I had a quick look at the vaadin docs and it seems that you have to implement the code for a service worker (therefore they also suggest to use PWABuilder from Microsoft for that). So vaadin "serves" PWA files for you, but you have to create and reference them. At least we found the reason why you don't get any A2HS pop up dialog.